# Input and Ouput in R, avoid writing and reading with a function (train_word2vec() - WordVectors)

Tags: r, output

For a project I use the R package wordVectors, and the function **train_word2vec()**     [see an example here](http://www.rpubs.com/mukul13/rword2vec)

**My first question:** 
This function requires a train_file, which is a single .txt file (on your computer). For now, you have to store this file in a specific directory in your computer. But I have the file also in my R environment (in a data.frame, within the column called: text  (df$text) ).

I want to avoid reading the .txt file, but instead use an R data.frame with text. Is there a workaround?

**My second question:** 
The same function (train_word2vec) has a 'ouput' parameter, described as 'Path of the output file'. Again, I don't want to get anything on my computer, so is there a workaround that I can store the output model (let's say "vec.bin"), in my R environment (R-script)?

CODE:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mukul13/rword2vec")
library(rword2vec)

model=word2vec(train_file = "text8",output_file = "vec.bin",binary=1)

# Instead of "text8" I want to insert a data.frame column (containing text).
# Instead of "vec.bin" I want to have something Like "foo <- vec.bin" in R. So that the output stays within R and not on my PC.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rword2vec` is a thin wrapper around `word2vec`, a program written in C that expects to read from training a training file and write to an output file. See for example here: https://github.com/mukul13/rword2vec/blob/master/R/word2vec.R#L28. The corresponding C function is here: https://github.com/mukul13/rword2vec/blob/master/src/word2vec.c#L638. There is no way to read or write `data.frame`s there.

Have you tried [text2vec](https://cran.r-project.org/package=text2vec) as an alternative? At least at first sight it looks more flexible.